# Aspect and tense for the verb Войти/Bxодить

Tags: глаголы-движения, вид

In a charming old book "Russian Through Pictures" designed by Harvard University we have a picture of a mother and daughter preparing to enter a shop, and the text underneath says

> Они войдут в магазин.

In the next picture we see them entering the shop and the text is

> Они входят в магазин.

I thought I knew the difference between determinate/one direction  (
*Идти*) and indeterminate/several directions (*Ходить*), but surely the determinacy of this action shouldn't change according to the tense?
So why the actual change here?
I suppose the preposition "в" explains the apparent paradox, but what is the exact rule?
In the books I consulted they explain at length the semantic differences between *Идти* and
Ходить
and  conjugate them, but they don't conjugate these verbs with prepositions added.

Comment: _Входить_ (and _выходить_) is a different verb than _ходить_.

Comment: @mustaccio: I know, that's why I talked of prefixes. Yet these verbs have the same root.

Comment: Ходить, входить, выходить, отходить,  уходить/// Идти, войти, выйти, отойти, уйти /// I do not know what the rule sounds like, but I tried to analyze several verbs. It seems that the rule sounds like this: prefix + unidirectional verb = perfect verb. Prefix + multidirectional verb = imperfect verb. // *Входить в магазин* — to be in the process of entering the store. *Войти в магазин* — to be in the store due to the completion of the login process.

Comment: @Sergey Slepov: Thanks for adding in your edit  the (for some reason) missing "н" in "магазин".

Answer (score 3):

Just as @mustaccio mentioned, you should treat входить/войти separately from the ходить/идти even though they are related morphologically. It's just "enter" in imperfective/perfective aspect respectively.
Therefore, it's simply "they will enter the store" and "they enter (are entering) the store"

Answer (score 2):

Key phrase - In the next picture! This means that

> 'Они войдут в магазин' - this is their intention to enter the store / they are ready to do it / they will do it very soon.
>
> In the second picture, 'Они входят в магазин', i.e. they are performing that action at that moment. This is what happened after the moment captured in the first picture.

In elementary school, we were taught to use questions:

> Они что сделают? - Войдут (future tense).
>
> Они что делают? - Входят (present tense).

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry. So this is not evident, even for a native Russian speaking child?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I think so. For children 5 or 6 years old. Аthough it depends very much on the knowledge (or rather experience) of the child. The child may know when to use which word, but cannot explain why